# Force fast-forward master branch to another

Tags: git

Say I have two branch topic and master.

```
     F---C'---D'---E (more)   topic
    /
A---B---C---D                 master
```

The two branch are orignally diverged at D. However, I injected another commit on branch topic with `rebase -i`, so they're now diverged at B.

Now I want the master to adopt the commit F, as well as C and D which are unchanged. (I tried merge but it will make a merge commit)

The desired result:

```
                 E --- (more)     topic
                /
A---B---F---C---D                 master
```

What's the preferred way to do it?

Comment: I think doing another interactive rebase is how I would do this.  There does not seem to be a clean way (e.g. simple rebase) to achieve what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, to `pick F` on master between B and C?

Comment: Yes, and then deal with `E` and everything after that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Ugh I can't seem to fast forward even if the C and D are equivalent, how should I merge till D?

Comment: Merging and fast forwarding won't work here and won't give you the desired result.  Do another interactive rebase and rebuild `master` the way you want it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's bad... Anyway thanks a lot.